# Pass TimeRange Objects with SelectList and DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have passed values before with @Html.DropDownList with SelectList before and like this it works just fine:
In my Controller:

```
ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "Address.City");
```

In my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="location" class="control-label"></label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.location.LocationId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Locations, "Wähle Standort", new { @class = "form-control", id = "location" });
      <span asp-validation-for="location" class="text-danger" id="locationError"></span>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to pass entire objects, because they do not have an ID, but it is not working:

In my controller:

```
IList<TimeRange> availableSlots = ahbvm.GetAvailableSlots(b.location.LocationId, b.ev.socketType);
ViewBag.Slots = new SelectList(availableSlots);
```

In my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="slot" class="control-label"></label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.slot, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Slots, "Wähle Zeitraum", new { @class = "form-control" })
     <span asp-validation-for="slot" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The DropdownList is populated with the right values, but when I submit it the TimeRange is not set or passed, the ID (`<input type="hidden" asp-for="requestID">`) however is passed, so values in general are submitted on click

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.slot, new SelectList(ViewBag.slots, "yourvaluefield", "displayName"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have missed to specify `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` properties of `SelectList` for `Slots`. This:

```
ViewBag.Slots = new SelectList(availableSlots);
```

should be like as follows: (Like you did for `Locations`)

```
ViewBag.Slots = new SelectList(availableSlots, "IdField", "TextField");
```

See how to initialize [`SelectList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_):

> Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the
> specified items for the list, the data value field, and the data text
> field.

```
public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

Comment: But TimeRange objects in the list do not have an ID and I want to see start and end, so which values can I use for dataValueFiled/dataTextField?

Comment: Yes It does not have to be "ID" for dataValueField, put value that is unique for that Item.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I thought, since SelectList does have this constructor (SelectList(IEnumerable) , it's possible to pass just the entire list to the view. Since my list does not have a unique value (possible duplicates of start/end times) I created a new model with time range and id.